# Getting started with Django, Heroku and Amazon

Tags: python, django, heroku, amazon-web-services

I want to change my static website (http://ingledow.co.uk) to a Django site on Heroku and Amazon using GitHub to store the code.

I've been through the Django tutorial once, so I'm fairly new to the whole thing.

Where would you guys start with this?  Any useful books, code learning websites you could recommend to get started?

Thanks
David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To easily understand and visualize Heroku when hosting Django apps I created this drawing for our startup ChattyHive. I hope it is helpful. Don't hesitate on asking me any doubt or suggest anything :)

(please right clic on it and "view picture" to see it full size or it will be too small!)

[image: Heroku Overview for ChattyHive]

Answer (score 3):

The best way to learn Python and Django is to be comfortable with creating a proper environment for developing your application, although you can skip the details and start with Heroku's [official guide](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-django) on how to manage a Django application across the whole stack.

At the time of writing, these are some of the essential tools Python developers should be comfortable with:

- [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) for creating distinct copies of the Python interpreter and it's environment
- [pip](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/index.html) for managing Python dependencies
- [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.7/) for defining administrative tasks across all your target environments
- [puppet](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/) or [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/) for provisioning environments
- [vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com/) for provisioning development environments

I would suggest that you immediately familiarize yourself with vagrant and focus on the virtualenv+pip+fabric trio--these are ubiquitously utilized in any Python web project and your bound to be forced to come to terms with them sooner or later, so get straight to it and you'll be otherwise amazed how you ever managed any Python development without them.

As far as learning Django is concerned, you will need to understand that Django *is still* just plain-old Python, what [WSGI applications](http://wsgi.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are, how domain objects are [modeled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/), how Django [routes requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/), how views [handle requests](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/) and how they [produce responses](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/), including additional and intermediary framework components. Afterwards, you should be knowledgeable enough to start tackling any requirements you might have of your application.

I will stress that having a good grasp on Python goes a long way in helping you understand how Django was designed and how to better write and organize your application's sources. The documentation is pretty exhaustive and it's the primary resource for any developer, but if you find yourself in need, there are several good books written that focus on providing additional material on certain aspects, but never forget to hone your Python skills.

Worth mentioning is the [Django Package index](https://www.djangopackages.com/) which tracks any Python package specifically written to be integrated with Django. Their repositories are publicly accessible either on Github or Bitbucket and they range from tiny to huge and are an invaluable resource to see how other developers are doing Django development right.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should start with some introduction books about Django,like The Django Book.